# Spring JPA @Param of filename for postgres COPY

Tags: postgresql, file, csv, spring-data-jpa, sqlbulkcopy

I have the following interface which is connected to a PostgreSQL database:

```
public interface ExampleDAO extends JpaRepository<Example, Integer>
{
    @Modifying
    @Query(value="COPY my_table FROM :filename CSV HEADER", nativeQuery=true)
    public int copyMyTable(@Param("filename") String filename);
}
```

But when I run it I get

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
```

I remove the `@Param` and hardcode the filename in and it works fine. The filename passed is:

```
copyMyTable("C:\\path\\to\\my\\file.csv");
```

I am totally at a loss on this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging [from this thread](https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/1893680) Postgres doesn't support bind parameters in this kind of statement.

Comment: Thank you for finding the clarity on this! I ended up reading the file in Java line by line and doing the inserts/updates via JPA save function, the file is less than 100 lines so performance is no issue.